# android export, Command-line Error -1073741819

Tags: android, command-line, export

I don't know why got this error! when export a project in android

failed to export application
Command-line Error -1073741819

and no error message and logs..

but, another project is possible to export..

What is the Error -1073741819 on Command-line?

Answer (score 1):

I got this also today, after Eclipse installed some updates. It seems "L" related.
Then I deleted the "bin" and "gen" folders of the project and it worked again...